# Cannot convert type T to T[] when I call SP in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a simple SP called 'prcGetCOBAdress' using parameter for number of records return and address search.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcGetCOBAddress] 
    @NumberOfRecord int,
    @FullAddress nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @fullAdd nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE @numRec int

    SET @fullAdd = @fullAddress
    SET @numRec = @numberOfRecord

    SELECT TOP (@numRec)
      ,[UID_NUM]
      ,[ADD_FULL]
      ,[FLOOR]
      ,[POSTALCITY]
      ,[STATE]
      ,[ZIP5]
      ,[IN_OUT], and more...

  FROM [ISD].[dbo].[view_COBADDRESS]
  WHERE [ACTIVE] = 1 AND [ADD_FULL] LIKE '%'+@fullAdd+'%'

END
```

then I create a class called 'AddressALL' like below

```
namespace GISWebApplication
{
    public class AddressALL
    {
        public double UID_NUM { get; set; }
        public string ADD_FULL { get; set; }
        public string POSTALCITY { get; set; }
and more....

    }
}
```

Finally I create a web service like below to call this stored procedure from EF like below

```
public AddressALL[] getAddesses(int NumberOfRecords, string AddressInput)
{
    AddressALL result = new AddressALL();
    try
    {
        using (GISAddressEntities database = new GISAddressEntities())
        {
            result = database.prcGetCOBAddress(NumberOfRecords, AddressInput).ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return result;
}
```

However I have error saying cannot implicitly convert AddressALL to Address[] at result line.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `result` variable as single object, not as array:

```
AddressALL result = new AddressALL();
```

That gives you an error when you try to assign array of `AddressALL` objects to `result` variable. Use

```
AddressALL[] result = null;
// or
AddressALL[] result = new AddressALL[0];
```

Or just don't use local variable for storing result. Also I would not return empty array in case of exception. Thus you will not know whether there is an error or just no addresses found. It's better not to catch error or wrap it in more high-level exception:

```
public AddressALL[] getAddesses(int NumberOfRecords, string AddressInput)
{
    try
    {
        using (GISAddressEntities database = new GISAddressEntities())
            return database.prcGetCOBAddress(NumberOfRecords, AddressInput).ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new DataAccessException("Failed to load addresses", ex);
    }
}
```

One more note - if you are creating web application, then writing error to console is not good solution :) Use some logging framework and log errors to file.

UPDATE: You have another problem - stored procedure returns `Address` objects instead of `AddressALL` objects. And `AddressALL` is not derived from `Address`. If set of fields is same, you can simply tell EF to return `AddressALL` entity as described [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx).

Comment: error at "return result" goes away but still error out at "result = database.prcGetCOBAddress(NumberOfRecords, AddressInput).ToArray();"

Comment: @MikeJun you are probably still missing square brackets on variable declaration

Comment: I did use brackets but still error out at "return database.prcGetCOBAddress......." saying same error message

Comment: When I add .Select then it works but it seem like duplication and waste code. I already define columns in AddressAll class and I don't understand why I need to use Select to match columns in AddressAll Class. database.prcGetCOBAddress(NumberOfRecords, AddressInput).Select(p => new AddressALL{UID_NUM = (double)p.UID_NUM,and more}).ToArray();

Comment: @MikeJun seems like you are not returning objects of `AddressALL` type from your `prcGetCOBAddress` method. Duck typing is not working in C#. If two classes have same properties, classes are still different.